# C# save txt file on desktop

Tags: c#, .net, file, desktop

How can I save a txt file that it was created by me on desktop?

This is the code:

```
void CreaTxtBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    filePath = filePath + @"\Error Log\";
    TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"Gara.txt");

    int rowcount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    for(int i = 0; i < rowcount - 1; i++){
        sw.WriteLine(
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + '\t' +
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + '\t' +
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + '\t' +
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + '\t' +
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString() + '\t' +
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString() + '\t' +
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString() + '\t' +
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString() + '\t'
        );
    }
    sw.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("File txt creato correttamente");
}
```

I thought that with these instructions

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
filePath = filePath + @"\Error Log\";
TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"Gara.txt");
```

I can save the file on Desktop, but the txt is created correctly in the wrong path.
How can I fix it?

Comment: where did it save?

Comment: In the program's folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've constructed your `filePath`, but haven't used it in `TextWriter`. Instead you're just writing to `Gara.txt` file which is by default located in the folder where your application started in.

Change your code to something like:

```
 filePath = filePath +@"\Error Log\Gara.txt";
 TextWriter sw= new StreamWriter(filePath);
```

Comment: Note that it is preferred to use `Path.Combine()` instead of string concatenation to build up file paths .

Comment: And also note that the default is the directory that the application was started in, not the directory where the executable is located. E.g. if you currently are in directory `C:\tmp` and you start your app in `C:\Program Files\SomeFolder\MyApp.exe`, the current directory will be `C:\tmp` (unless it is changed by your app or a parameter when starting the process, e.g. by using the `start` command).

Answer (score 7):

You have to *combine* all path parts into the final `filePath`:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), 
  "Error Log",
  "Gara.txt");
```

I suggest using *Linq* to save the data which is more readable and easier to maintain:

```
File
  .WriteAllLines(filePath, dataGridView1
    .Rows
    .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => string.Join("\t", row
       .Cells
       .OfType<DataGridViewCell>()
       .Take(8) // if grid has more than 8 columns (and you want to take 8 first only)
       .Select(cell => cell.Value)) + "\t")); // + "\t": if you want trailing '\t'
```

Comment: You are missing the last `'\t'` at the end of each line.

Comment: @Maarten: I see, thank you! However, it may well occur, that the last *trailing tabulation* is in fact redundant (so I've added the comment)

Comment: The trailing `\t` looks like a bug to me, actually (but of course we don't know the exact spec of the file format. Might be that such an oddity actually is required). Nevertheless, this solution elegantly avoids lots of string concatenations by using a string builder (writing out directly to the stream without building up a line might be even more efficient).